# How to switch 64 bit matlab to 32 bit mode

Tags: matlab

I have some data files which are compatible with only 32 bit matlab.
However, my matlab is 64 bit.

is it possible to switch   64 bit matlab to 32 bit mode?
If yes, how?
Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible (not even on OS X where some applications permit this). You'll either need to install a 32-bit version or re-compile the executables.

Comment: What data do you have? Typically you only have issues with runnable code but not with data.

Comment: i have numerical data files and fortran exe files run under matlab,